# Fill available space Compound component constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

How can I make two Compound Component made of a constraint layout fill the entire width of the screen (Each component using exactly half the screen width)?

[image]

I am not sure what should be the layout_width specified in the component and what should be the layout_width specified in the activity layout.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**NavTextDrawer.kt**:

```
class NavTextDrawer(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
  init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navtextdrawer, this)
  }
}
```

**navtextdrawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:text="TEST!@#"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.testproj.NavTextDrawer
    android:id="@+id/cog"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.example.testproj.NavTextDrawer
    android:id="@+id/sog"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cog"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sog"` to your `cog` View

```
<com.example.testproj.NavTextDrawer
    android:id="@+id/cog"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sog"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```